# How to display custom help message when only 'help' is inputted on the command line?

Tags: python

Currently my program works by taking in two arguments after the program name in the terminal.

i.e. `python myscript.py file1 file2` works

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as a, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as b:
    while True:
        try: 
    #there are two while loops here, one for each file...
```

How can I change it so that when I type in just:

```
$python myprogram.py help
```

A help message (from a text file I have made) is generated?

Is there a very simple way of doing this?

Comment: Compare `sys.argv[1]` to `help` and display help in that case, instead of running your normal code?

Comment: Sure, check if the first argument is `help` and then print something.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), it will make your life easier while dealing with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a check of `sys.argv[1]` and see if it equals "help".

```
if sys.argv[1] == "help":
```

In this block, you then print out your help file to the user.

```
if sys.argv[1] == "help":
    with open("help_readme.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
```

If `sys.argv[1]` does not equal "help", continue with your current logic.

---

An alternative is to utilize [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). It can automatically generate the "help" for you when you pass `-h`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some files.')
parser.add_argument('file', nargs=2, help="List of two files to process")

args = parser.parse_args()

for f in args.file:
    print(f)   # This shows how to use the file name. You will want your logic here
```

Using this, if you pass `-h` to your command line, you get a helpful message like so:

```
usage: test.py [-h] file file

Process some files.

positional arguments:
  file        List of two files to process

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

It will accept 2 file names. If you pass anything other than two values, it will produce an appropriate response.